# Diagonals in North East Direction - Time Limit Exceeded in Python 3.8.3

Tags: python-3.x, list, matrix, optimization

The program must accept an integer matrix of size `RxC` as the input. The program must print the integers in the diagonals in the `North-East directions` of the matrix in the seprate line as output.

```
Boundary:
2<=R,C<=100
Time Limit : 500ms
```

Example 1:

```
Input:
3 3
73 77 76
71 17 87
37 73 98

Output:
73
71 77
37 17 76
73 87
98
```

Example 2:

```
Input:
4 6
97 78 7 39 92 45
68 100 49 95 97 100
59 41 81 22 26 100
46 37 81 12 93 10

Output:
97
68 78
59 100 7
46 41 49 39
37 81 95 92
81 22 97 45
12 26 100
93 100
10
```

My Code:

```
row,col = map(int,input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(row)]
# Redundancy of row and col 
rep = []
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        b = []
        for k in range(i,row):
            if (j,k) not in rep:
                b.append(matrix[k][j])
                rep.append((j,k))
            j-=1
            if j<0:break
        if len(b):print(*(b[::-1]))
```

My code works well but when the matrix is of size (100,100) it exceeds the given time limit, is there a way to reduce it. Thanks in advance

***Note : No External Libraries should be used!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to realize that because each number only appears in the solution once, so we really only need to evaluate each value once.

We can also see that each matrix will result in `row + col - 1` number of North-East direction diagonals, which will help us.

```py
# Original code
row,col = map(int,input().split())
# I won't turn them into ints, strings actually make it easier for my work
matrix = [input().split() for i in range(row)]

diagonals = [""] * (row + col - 1)

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        # determine which diagonal the number belongs to, and prepend it
        diagonals[i + j] = "%s %s" % (matrix[i][j], diagonals[i + j])

# print out diagonals one at a time
for diagonal in diagonals: print(diagonal)
```

I never got the chance to run it, but this should give the general idea!

(new to SO, plz be nice :D)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but check by running it in online compilers with the given input because it doesn't give the desired output . Thanks for your efforts

Comment: What does it output? Maybe it's something I can debug?

Comment: Check the edit now i have done it with the print statement . @M Z Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I actually realized my error, I think you might like this solution better :D

Comment: Yup It worked but thanks for your answer, and one more issue i have debugged it the None also gets printed out :D Now It's Done :D

Comment: Haha, yeah, I forgot to put that in the edited answer, it's in there now!